# RxJS: SwitchMap for Array of Strings

Tags: rxjs

Following use case: A user can join 0...* groups. Each group has an ID and contains 0...* posts.

I subscribe to an Observable (to get the groups of the user he joined) and this returns an array of strings (the group IDs).

```
const groupIds$ = of(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

If I only had one I would now use `switchMap` and return this new observable and subscribe to it to get the posts from the group.

But so I have an array and so this isn't working.  Does anyone has an idea which RxJS operator(s) can achieve this to get the posts from all groups?

Or does no operator for such use case exist and I have to do it separately at subscribe?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do. You want to make an Observable for each item in `groupIds$` and subscribe to all of them? Or you want subscribe only to the one that emits first?

Comment: The first one: I want to make an Observable for each item in groupIds$ and subscribe to all of them. As I said if I had only one I would use switchMap and subscribe to that new observable, but with an array of strings this isn't possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ideally `forkJoin` if you know you'll have all source Observables as an array:

```
groupIds$.pipe(
  concatMap(groups => {
    const observables = groups.map(id => ...);
    return forkJoin(...observables);
  })
).subscribe(...);
```

`forkJoin` will emit a single array with all the results in the same order as in `groupIds$`.

Eventually if you don't care about the order and just want to get all the results in parallel you can use `merge` instead of `forkJoin` (I mean the "Observable creation method" called `merge` imported directly from `rxjs`. Not the `merge` operator from `'rxjs/operators'`).

Comment: forkJoin isn't working because it's only emit if the observable completes. My Observable does not complete because if new posts arriving of the group, it will be emitted. But merge seems to be working :) THANKS!

Instead of concatMap I use switchMap ;)

Answer (score 5):

Everyone who arrives at this question, here is the answer for "switchMap for Array of strings" (thanks to martin). You only have to use 'merge' from 'rxjs' (not the operator!). Inside switchMap return merge and you are done:

```
groupIds$.pipe(
    switchMap(groups => {
        const observables = groups.map(id => {
            // your function that returns the observable
            return something.getObservable(id);
        });
        return merge(...observables);
    })
).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('DATA', data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html.

```
const groupIds$ = of(['a', 'b', 'c']);

const myPromise = id =>
  new Promise(resolve => resolve(something.getPostsByGroupId(id)));

const posts$ = groupIds$.pipe(
  mergeMap(
    id => myPromise(id),
    (valueFromSource, valueFromPromise) => {
      return valueFromPromise;
    }));

posts$.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: That's not working because "id" from `mergeMap(id => {...})` is still an array

Comment: That would only work if I have a final value, but my observable is a stream that not complete, but I already found a solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/53286688/8971128

Answer (score 0):

**Terser improvement on great existing answers.** This emits an array of all posts each time the `groupIds$` source emits.

```js
groupIds$.pipe(
  switchMap(ids => zip(...ids.map(id => service.getPosts(id)))),
  map((posts: Array<Post[]>) => [].concat.apply([], posts))
).subscribe(posts => /*is an array of all posts*/);
```